# How to display arabic characters from oracle database in asp classic

Tags: vbscript, oracle11g, asp-classic, adodb

My ASP classic application is connecting to Oracle 11g through ADODB as follows:

```
Set Connection1 = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") 
Set Recordset = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
Connection1.Open = "Data Source=PIPCP;User Id=PIP104;Password=xxxxxxxxxxxx"
SQL = "Select CUST_NAME FROM PIP_CUST_HEAD;"
Recordset.Open SQL, Connection1
```

and displaying the value as follows:

```
Response.Write Recordset("CUST_NAME")
```

The value always gets displayed as:

```
???? ??????
```

I have tried the following but unsuccessful:

Meta Tag:

```
<meta content="html/text; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
```

CodePage:

```
Response.CodePage = 65001
```

Charset:

```
Response.Charset = "UTF-8"
```

Language and codepage combination

```
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001"%>
```

Queried the data in TOAD and got the Arabic text without any problem, so the database collation is good. It can store Arabic values and displays Arabic values.

I tried manually entering Arabic text in the ASP page and it gets displayed without any problem.

Also tried without charset, codepage and meta tag.

The data is being retrieved through ODBC. I tried retrieving data from multiple servers with different configuration, it still doesn't get displayed properly.

Believe me, I have been finding a solution for this problem for days and I have searched everywhere, tried all solutions.

How can I solve this problem? Any suggestions or solutions will be appreciable. Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you've done everything you need to do on the Classic ASP side, `Response.CodePage = 65001` is usually the key to making things work, so I suspect that the problem lies on the Oracle side?  I don't know anything about Oracle specifically, but is it possible that your data is being stored using a character encoding other than UTF-8.  Alternatively the problem may be with the connector - I know that there's an old version of a MySQL ODBC connector which some webhosts still use which doesn't support UTF-8

Comment: Try adding `charset=AL32UTF8` or `charset=UTF8` to your connection string.  Another option is to use the OLEDB provider instead of the ODBC provider which is supposed to handle charsets natively

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/win.112/e17726.pdf  (page 39)

Comment: @SeanRingel as John has pointed out it entirely depends on whether they are using UTF-8 in Oracle, my guess is probably not.

Comment: Changing from ODBC to OLEDB did the trick !!! Had some problem as I was getting invalid character error but that was due to using semicolon at the end of the query, after removing, it is working perfectly fine. Thanks to @SeanRingel for pointing about out the provider.

Comment: Although your get the solution but still here another solution - What is the file encoding type. I faced same error when I had file with ANSI encoding. I just changed it to UTF-8 and placed chartset="UTF-8" meta tag.